# Hot Swap,Hot Reload,Live Reload

Tags: spring-boot, livereload, hotswap, hot-reload

[image]

I feel quite confused with the three words, what's the difference between them? The picture is from [Hot Swapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)

Answer (score 2):

To put in my few words, I would say

**LiveReload** - is immediate reflection of HTML/CSS file changes on the browser that the application is open at.

**HotSwap** - is immediate implementation of the changes you make to the classes. Say the *controller* class. I would relate this with the *classloader*.

**HotReload** - is automatic loading of the application when any changes detected. This is to avoid the developer's effort of stopping, re-starting the Spring Boot application manually.

Edits/Comments/Improvements welcome.